# How to hide optgroup label?

Tags: html, html-select, optgroup

I need to get rid of labels in optgroups.

From this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn5e5.png

Into this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvRM7.png

But I need to do this with opgroups. I don`t want to delete them.

```
<select>
  <optgroup>
    <option>1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup>
    <option>2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup>
    <option>4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upXn8/

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to use `<optgroup>` without rendering it. The label and indentation of child options is the only benefit I'm aware of.

Comment: I need to style every option independently. The only solution as I know is to style optgroup. But they have those spacings, which i don`t want.

Comment: I'd recommend using classes on the `<option>` elements themselves. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/upXn8/8/

Comment: If you style `<option>` you have very limited functionality. For example, you can`t do this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upXn8/7/)

Comment: Interesting. I'd be concerned about browser compatibility when it comes to this. Your example looks really strange in Chrome, as the font changes for the indentation as well, misaligning the names.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need to have different fonts and that is the best solution for me at the moment. If you know another way tell me please.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but:

```
optgroup { display: none; }
```

This is not going to work in some browsers because it is going to hide the `optgroup` element but options are children of that element and so they will be hidden too. You *could* set a `display` on the child elements but in my experience this doesn't work.

A correct (and more semantically correct!) version that will work (tested in Chrome 42 and IE 11) is the following:

```
optgroup {
  visibility: hidden;
}
optgroup option {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This will unfortunately keep the spacing that the `optgroup` applies (as it doesn't remove the optgroup element from flow, it just makes it invisible), and that spacing is not padding/margin, so this is far from ideal.

Not so sure of browser compatibility, however.

Answer (score 2):

this is better, try it!

```
optgroup {
        color: transparent;
        height: 0px;
    }

    optgroup option {
        color: inherit;
    }
```

Comment: nice approach, but doesn't work on my chrome 88. the gap is still there

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same color as the optgroup background and set another color for option

```
optgroup{
    color:white;
}

optgroup option{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: color: transparent is much better approach. however it won't solve problem yet

Answer (score -3):

```
select optgroup {
    display:none;
}
```

This will not work on `firefox`. You display none will make all option in group disappear.